# E/SurfaceSyncer( 8706): Failed to find sync for id=0

Tags: flutter, dart, intellij-idea

since a few days, when I run the emulator, the last two lines of the terminal are these:

```
E/SurfaceSyncer( 8706): Failed to find sync for id=0
W/Parcel  ( 8706): Expecting binder but got null!
```

the IDE is intelliJ

Can someone explain to me what error it is?

should i try to fix it?

the emulator works

I have tried to delete the emulator data (I saw somewhere that it could be a solution) but not in my case

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be just a warning and can be safely ignored if the emulator works without issues with the Flutter app. This [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/123255) mentioned that a fix has been rolled out to suppress these warnings.